# suggestions on how to make the function more generic(c# .net -> exporting to csv)

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

so I have the following function

```
DataTable GetData()
{
string chargeMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM");
var creationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
string creationTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");
string constVal = "MLL";
string fileType = "HIYUV-CHEVRA";
string fileName;

var connectString = "Data Source=192.168.117.1;User ID=*;Password=*";
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = connectString;
con.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from BAKASHOT_PIRTY_MEIDA WHERE PROD IS NULL and CHARGED = 0";
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());              
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
DataTable db = new DataTable();
if (row[3].ToString() == "10")
{
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from BAKASHOT_PIRTY_MEIDA WHERE COMPANY_ID = " + row[3].ToString() + " and PROD IS NULL and CHARGED = 1";
//compId = company_id's value
string compId = row[3].ToString();
fileName = constVal + "-" + fileType + "-" + compId + "-" + chargeMonth + "-" + creationDate + "-" + creationTime + ".csv";

db.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
ExportExcelGeneric(db, fileName);
}
if (row[3].ToString() == "1000")
{
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from BAKASHOT_PIRTY_MEIDA WHERE COMPANY_ID = " + row[3].ToString() + " and PROD IS NULL and CHARGED = 1";
string compId = row[3].ToString();
fileName = constVal + "-" + fileType + "-" + compId + "-" + chargeMonth + "-" + creationDate + "-" + creationTime + ".csv";

db.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
ExportExcelGeneric(db, fileName);
}
}
con.Close();
return dt;
}
```

and this is my csv function:

```
  void ExportExcelGeneric(DataTable ds, string filename)
            {

                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\" + filename, false);
                string y = "D:\\" + filename;
                //headers    
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(ds.Columns[i]);
                    if (i < ds.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(",");
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                        {
                            string value = dr[i].ToString();
                            if (value.Contains(','))
                            {
                                value = String.Format("\"{0}\"", value);
                                sw.Write(value);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        if (i < ds.Columns.Count - 1)
                        {
                            sw.Write(",");
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
```

What it does is basically check for company_id value under company_id column's value taken from database and creates a csv for that specific ID..
as it is now, if for example I have 40records of `(row[3].ToString() == "10")` the loop will go in every row and do the select query, I want to somehow skip that, and say like : "if you got a companyId of 10, skip the rest until u reach the next one which is 1000, and to make query from database only once per Company_ID.
also, Im trying to avoid hardcoding the companyId in my if statements and Im not kinda sure how to do that., also, Im making the first select and inserting into a datatable before my statements just so I have a variable I can iterate through otherwise I couldnt.. which seems odd and bad practice aswell.
Im pretty new to programming, making everything generic is still tough and I'd like to get some opinions and help .

thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: I would use a DataAdpater to fill a datatable.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter?view=netframework-4.8&force_isolation=true  The use code ToCsv to convert table to CSV : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/export-datatable-to-csv-using-extension-method/?force_isolation=true

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to create an SQL command. Use parameterized statements. See [why it's a bad idea and how to fix it](//bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @gunr2171 okay I see, thanks, but wouldnt it be effective only when taking an input ? so the user doesnt change values?